# Change speed of rate of unit change in Trigger function

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I am trying to build an interactive model but I am facing some problems.

for example:

```
Column[
 {Manipulator[Dynamic[s], {1, 10, 1}, Appearance -> "Open"],
  Trigger[Dynamic[n], {0, 200, 1}, Dynamic[s], 
   AnimationRepetitions -> \[Infinity], 
   AppearanceElements -> {"PlayPauseButton", "ResetButton"}],
  Dynamic[n]}]
```

If you run this code and start the `Trigger`, when you try to change the speed of the `Trigger` using `Manipulator`, the value of Trigger jumps up and down.

I want to change the speed of rate of change of `n` starting from the current value of `n`.

Any help (other solution) will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: i dont know if this solves your problem, but...try this:     Animator[Dynamic[n], {0, 10, 1}, AnimationRate -> 20, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding `Trigger`. It internally uses one `Clock[]`. Changing `s` only changes how the current value of that `Clock[]` is displayed.

Comment: @Karsten7. Thank you for your answer to the question. it really helps me. can you explain your comment in more details. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one potential alternative to using `Trigger`.

```
DynamicModule[{n = 1, ss = Infinity, s},
 Column[{Manipulator[Dynamic[s, TrackedSymbols :> {}], {1, 10, 1}, Appearance -> "Open"], 
   Row[{Dynamic[Refresh[n++, UpdateInterval -> Max[1/s, ss], TrackedSymbols :> {}], 
      n--, TrackedSymbols :> {ss}, UpdateInterval -> Infinity], Spacer[10], 
     ButtonBar[{"reset" :> (n = 0; ss = -ss; ss = -ss;), "stop" :> (ss = Infinity; n--;), 
       Dynamic@If[ss == Infinity && n == 1, "start", "continue"] :> (ss = 0;)}]}]}]]
```

[image: ScreenGIF]

This one is a little nicer

```
DynamicModule[{n = 0, playQ = False, s},
 Column[{Manipulator[Dynamic[s, TrackedSymbols :> {}], {1, 10, 1}, Appearance -> "Open"], 
   Row[{DynamicWrapper[Dynamic[n], 
      Refresh[If[playQ, n = Mod[n + 1, 200]], UpdateInterval -> 1/s, 
       TrackedSymbols :> {}], TrackedSymbols :> {playQ}, UpdateInterval -> Infinity], 
     Spacer[10], 
     ButtonBar[{Tooltip[Framed[Graphics[{Line[{{-0.75, 0}, {-0.75, 1}}], EdgeForm[Black], 
            Transparent, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {-0.7, 0.5}}]}, 
           PlotRange -> {{-0.9, 0.2}, {-0.1, 1.1}}, ImageSize -> 10]],
          "Reset"] :> (playQ = ! playQ; n = 0; playQ = ! playQ;), 
       Dynamic@Which[! playQ && n == 0, 
          Tooltip[Framed[Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0.5}}]}, ImageSize -> 10]], 
           "Start"], playQ, 
          Tooltip[Framed[Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{0.35, 0.2}, {0.35, 0.8}}], 
              Line[{{0.6, 0.2}, {0.6, 0.8}}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
            ImageSize -> 10]], "Stop"], ! playQ, 
          Tooltip[Framed[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Transparent, 
              Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0.5}}]}, ImageSize -> 10]],
            "Continue"]] :> (playQ = ! playQ;)}]}]}]]
```

[image: screenGIF2]

These two examples increase `n` directly roughly `s` times per second.
If it is important for your application to use a more precise timing, than these examples could be modified along the lines of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87743/18476) or [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96318/18476) answer.

[`Trigger`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trigger.html) isn't working the way as you seem to be expecting it to work. It doesn't directly increase `n` in steps of one `s` times per second, but, similar to [`Animator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animator.html), uses something like [`Clock`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clock.html) internally. The state of that `Clock` is then used to set `n`. In your example that concrete means, that changing `s` only changes how `n` is calculated based on that `Clock`. For example, if `s` is increased by a factor of 10, then `n` will not only change 10 times faster, but also will be calculated as if it was increasing 10 times faster before.
This should be an illustrative example of the situation.

```
DynamicModule[{s},
 {Manipulator[Dynamic[s], {1, 10, 1}, Appearance -> "Open"], 
  Dynamic[Mod[Round[Clock[{0, Infinity}]*s], 200]]}]
```

[image: ClockExample]

Comment: Very nice solutions. Could you elaborate your previous comment?

Comment: Now I get it, thanks, wasn't expecting such design...

Comment: @karsten, yes I investigated the way `Triggers` works yesterday. I found same behaviour that you explain in your last example. Many thanks